# segfaults with strtok_r I'm missing something here

Tags: c

here is a snippet of my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void  something_wrong_really(char *str)
{
        char *savedptr = NULL;
        char *delim    = " ";

        for ( char *p = str ; ; p = NULL) {
                char *token = strtok_r(p, delim, &savedptr);
                if (token == NULL)
                        break;
                printf(" %s\n", token);
        }
}

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "Okay so lets split this and see how it works";
    something_wrong_really(str);
    return 0;
}
```

based on the `strtok_r` [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html)

*strtok_r(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE
           || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE*

so if I compile my program as

```
cc t.c -std=c99
```

I end up getting warning

```
t.c: In function 'something_wrong_really':
t.c:10:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtok_r' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   char *token = strtok_r(p, delim, &savedptr);
   ^
t.c:10:17: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   char *token = strtok_r(p, delim, &savedptr);
                 ^
```

whats worse on execution it `segfaults`

```
./a.out
Segmentation fault
```

corresponding trace

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a5af19 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7a5af19 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a61339 in printf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004005e2 in something_wrong_really (str=0x7fffffffe0a0 "Okay") at t.c:13
#3  0x0000000000400653 in main () at t.c:19
(gdb)
```

on the other hand thing seem to work perfectly fine when enabled one of these flags

```
 _SVID_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE
```

corresponding output

```
# cc t.c -std=c99 -D_BSD_SOURCE
#
#
# ./a.out
 Okay
 so
 lets
 split
 this
 and
 see
 how
 it
 works
#
```

any hints on why this behavior ?

---

so it seems the snippet in [strtok_r](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html)  manual

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
>   feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>    strtok_r(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE
>        || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE
> ```

is explained (very loosely) here [feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)

> The || means that in order to obtain the declaration of acct(2) from
>          , either of the following macro definitions must be made
>          before including any header files:
>
> ```
>        #define _BSD_SOURCE
>        #define _XOPEN_SOURCE        /* or any value < 500 */
>
>    Alternatively, equivalent definitions can be included in the compila‐
>    tion command:
>
>        cc -D_BSD_SOURCE
>        cc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE           # Or any value < 500
> ```

so as @Some programmer dude pointed out inclusion of those MACRO definitions is a must else it leads to UB which eventually is what happened here.

Comment: For one, the manual you are quoting clearly states you need to `#include<string.h>`, but this prevents the compiler warnings, not the segfault.

Comment: dumped full source including includes ;-)

Comment: Generally "implicit declaration of function" warnings should be treated as errors.

Comment: The latest edit is working fine for me.

Comment: Please note that compilers such as gcc, when set to compile in strict standard mode, typically refuse to allow non-standard junk in standard headers. `strtok_r` isn't standard, yet the POSIX crap insists that the function should be placed in a standard library header - in direct violation of the C standard. So it may be impossible to compile your program because of shortcomings of POSIX. I would advise to roll out your own thread-safe strtok instead, it is fairly trivial to do. It seems unlikely that the numerous design mistakes in POSIX will ever get fixed, so avoid it whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not use the correct enabling macro (`_POSIX_C_SOURCE` according to [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html)) then the function will not be automatically declared. That means the compiler must deduce the argument types, and more importantly the return type will automatically be `int` (as noted in the second warning message).

If the argument types or the return type are wrong, then that call will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and very likely crashes.

By adding the correct macros, the function will be properly declared in the header file, and the correct types for arguments and returned value will be used.

---

The problem here is probably the mismatched return type. On a 64-bit system pointers (like e.g. `char *`) are 64 bits wide, while `int` is usually only 32 bits wide. This mismatch in sizes will cause many pointers to be wrong, and attempting to use them is a great source of segmentation faults.

Comment: that seems to be the solution but I was not expecting a segfault for not defining the compilation option ;-( that seems weird to me.

Comment: @u__ Undefined behavior is a great way to get crashes *sometimes*.

Comment: @u__ I think that has something to do with the comment Somme programmer dude made to me earlier. You have besides to include the header also to define that your source is posix compatible. If the compiler doesn't see the arugments and provide wrong arguments to the function, bad stuff happens.